Alpine Linux+ldap_pam: can login through ssh, can't su or sudo with ldap accounts
I've installed nss-pam-ldapd on an Alpine Linux server, edited nslcd.conf to use an ldap server I have running elsewhere, and added "UsePAM yes" to /etc/ssh/sshd_config.  I have two local accounts, root and admin, and an ldap account, ldapuser

I can ssh into the server as admin or ldapuser
As admin I can run sudo -u ldapuser echo hello
As admin I can't run su ldapuser
As root I can su into admin and ldapuser
As ldapuser I can su into root and admin

In general everything seems to work perfectly if the only accounts involved have an entry in /etc/shadow.  Research on the internet seems to suggest I can fix any login problems with the /etc/pam.d config files but they don't seem to do anything for su.  As an experiment I commented out "auth sufficient pam_rootok.so" from /etc/pam.d/su and root is still able to su as any user without a password.

Rather than nss-pam-ldap, I think you would do better to install sssd & let it handle things through pam.

I followed the advice in Bob Goddards comment and used sssd.  I had to switch to Debian because sss appears to be highly dependent on glib.  There is an APK package but it's limited to testing and doesn't appear to have made progress in years, I can't get the source code to build, and I came across several attempts to build with musl libc but they all seem to fail due to missing glibc features.
